# How to save the webpage as cache in custom WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I want to save the webpages in sdcard when it loading in custom `WebView` and next time loading the same url I want to load it from cache and updates in the webpage should save in the cache.

Comment: this is a good question. i would also like to know how to do it in the background, without a webView (or without showing it , at least, using a service or something like that).

Comment: @Ribin Haridas download the html file and save it to sdcard.When u want to load the html just give the path of the html saved in sdcard and use webView.loadUrl("file://" + name_of_your_file); or  u can put html file in assets and from there u can load on web-view.

Comment: pratik saving is not an issue but after saving if any updations in the webpages must save in the same file. i want do the updates of webpage in asynchronous task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use Asynchtask and download html file ,code right into doBackground method and set html in onPostExicute method.